# Overlay first seconds of a video over the last seconds of the same video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to do the following with ffmpeg :

Replace the last *n* seconds of a video with the first *n* seconds of this same video. Those first *n* seconds would have to appear fading in.

To clarify, if *n* = 2 :

- Take the first 2 seconds, remove them from the beginning of the video.
- Overlay those 2 seconds on the last 2 seconds of the video, fading in (fade in time would also be *n*.

I have tried this command :

```
ffmpeg -i media.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=00:02,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [0:v]trim=02:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; [v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]" -map "[out]" output.mp4
```

which has absolutely no effect, output file is the same as my input file.

Any help ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Use

`ffmpeg -i media.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:n,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=st=0:d=n,format=yuva420p[v0]; [0:v]trim=n,format=yuva420p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; [v1][v0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[ol];[0:v]overlay,trim=n,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[out]" -map "[out]" output.mp4`

The first n seconds are extracted and have a fade applied and an opaque alpha channel added. The remainder of the video has a transparent alpha channel added. The first portion is appended to the 2nd one. This whole stream is then overlaid on the full original video stream. The portion of the overlay with transparent alpha is invisble so the base video shows through, but the last n seconds of the overlay, which is, in fact, the first n seconds the video but with fade applied, is overlaid on the last n seconds of the base video.

Comment: Why should the OP use this command? What does it do?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/843968)

Comment: @Burgi added explanation. It always provided an answer to the question.